# How to globally pause all tracks in a page if one is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, javascript-objects

I am making a audio player, that user can have multiple instances of the same player. So the plugin can be used multiple times within the same page. I could make it, but the problem is that various `Audio` objects can play together. So I am looking for a solution to pause other sounds globally and play the one that is clicked.

**Here is my code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jc71ctu/2/)**

```
$.fn.MusicPlayer = function() {

  var audio = new Audio();
  this.click(function() {
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      $(this).text('player >> playing...');
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      $(this).text('player >> paused!');
    }
  });

  this.each(function() {
    audio.src = $(this).data('track');
  });
};

$("#obj1").MusicPlayer();
$("#obj2").MusicPlayer();
```

Is that any way to make it work ?

Comment: do you mean you want to only allow one to play at a time?

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes exactly. .

Comment: Dirty way could be to have a global for the  selected player, then loop over all the players and stop all except the selected one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution given your current html would be something like this:

```
$('[data-track]:contains("playing")').click();
```

after line 6 of the js in your fiddle.

This identifies playable divs based on them having a data-track attribute, and ones that are currently playing based on them containing the text "playing". However, both of these seem volatile. It would probably be better to add a css class in order to uniquely identify playable divs. Further, you could have another class identify whether or not it's currently playing.

That line would become this:

```
$('.playable.playing').click();
$(this).addClass("playing");
```

The pause section of that method would receive this:

```
$(this).removeClass("playing");
```

Full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kghm7djf/